# Backplane vs Sticky Load balancer

Tags: redis, signalr, signalr-backplane

I am developing SignalR application.There will be multiple instances of my application running on different servers behind the load balancer. I read about the backplane and found out that it is mainly serves the purpose of server failure and  handles the request hops between multiple servers.(there might be another benefits).

Please consider below scenario and suggest if I still needs backplane.

I am using sticky load balancing(i.e. all subsequent request from client goes to same server) ? So there is no chance of request hops in good scenario.

How I handled server down scenario - When server goes down. Client tries to reconnect and gets "404-not found" error.At this time client start new connection and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason for having a backplane when developing `SignalR` application comes from the following scenario:

- let's say you have 2 web servers hosting your application, `serverA` and `serverB`
- you have 2 clients connecting to your application, `client1` who is served by `serverA` and `client2` who  is served by `serverB`

A good assumption when developing a `SignalR` application is that you want these 2 clients to communicate with one another. So `client1` sends a message to `client2`.

The moment `client1` sends a message, his request is completed by `server1`. But `server1` keeps a mapping of connected users in memory. It looks for `client2`, but `client2` is kept in  the memory of `serverB`,  so the message will never get there.

By using a backplane, basically every message that comes in one server is broadcast to all other servers.

> One solution is to forward messages between servers, using a component called a backplane. With a backplane enabled, each application instance sends messages to the backplane, and the backplane forwards them to the other application instances.

Taken from [SignalR Introduction to scaleout](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-in-signalr)

Be sure to check this [backplane with Redis from the SignalR documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis).

Hope this helps. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for reply .My application does not want communication between the clients. Its only between server and client. And any server can serve any client.  Do I still need backplain ?

Comment: What if the client has two instances of the application(so 2 tabs with the application )- will the requests from both be routed to the same server?

Comment: Yes.As the sticky bahaviour of load balancer is source IP based.

Comment: If you create a mapping between a user and his connections, I don't think that the backplane is required.